Syntactic function of subordinate clause


I will go if you come.


According to cgel, 'if' is a marker. But what is the syntactic function of 'you come'? Is that syntactic function coordinate, subordinate, head or something else?

Yᴏᴜʀ Qᴜᴇꜱᴛɪᴏɴꜱ Aʀᴇ Tᴏᴏ Sʜᴏʀᴛ: please put more effort into composing your questions, as it is unfair to expect others to put more effort into answering than you have put into asking. Tell us what led you to ask the question, such as some confusion or lack of clarity over some particular theory or model, what you think the answer may be, or why you question there even being a clear answer. What research into this matter did you do and where, and what in particular did you find there that seems unclear or conflicting to you? What is your own guess or guesses, and why do you think so?
